# Java Regular Expressions with whitespace

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I am trying to match a pattern like so:

TR @(any number of word characters go here):

So the pattern begins with TR then has one space then has @ and then has any characters and terminates with a :

Here is my regex: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TR\\s@[\\w]+:");`

It is working and for example will fail on:

TR @abcnews:

I think my error is with the whitespace.

Comment: This is certainly not the source of the mistake, but the `[]` around `\\w` are redundant.

Comment: Your regex matches your example string just fine. What is your problem?

Comment: Your regex also doesn't do exactly what you describe: it won't just match a single space after 'TR', but any whitespace character (space, tab, return, line feed, form feed, or vertical tab). You can use a literal space (`' '`) if you actually need a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uC8zB3)

Regex: `TR\s+@(\w+):`

This even backreferences the text, it accepts multiple spaces between the TR and @ so it would work pretty well for you, sir.

EDIT A java code that it's properly working:

```
Matcher ma = Pattern.compile("TR\\s+@(\\w+):").matcher("TR    @asdfasd:");
while (ma.find()) {
    System.out.println(ma.group(1));
}
```